# Wordpress / OptionTree reference in css

Tags: css, wordpress, tree

I use this plugin to dynamically change the CSS in a user friendly way within the WordPress backend:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/

I set it up, and appended it to the theme (not a plugin anymore) - this works.

What I don't get is that those inputs get actually changed. So I set up a input field where the user can add a `hexadecimalcode(colorpicker)` to change the background, or even the font color.

How do I get this information to change in my CSS? I tried:

```
body {
  {{custom_background_css}}
  background-color: {{custom_background_css|background-color}};
}
```

where `custom_background_css` the id of this input field is. but nothing changes. I also read the documentation but I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

To adjust theme options for CSS, you'll have to include the CSS in your header, or write a .php file that generates the CSS you want, and link to that.  But maybe the easiest way is to hook wp_head from functions.php, and write the code directly there. See below for a schematic example to add to your functions.php

```
// this is the hooked function
function add_css() {

    echo "dynamically generated CSS here";
}

// Add your wp_head hooks
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css', 5);
```